# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}((x+\frac{a}{n})^2+(x+\frac{2a}{n})^2+...+(x+\frac{(n-1)a}{n})^2)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't know how to transform the expression $\frac{1}{n}((x+\frac{a}{n})^2+(x+\frac{2a}{n})^2+...+(x+\frac{(n-1)a}{n})^2)$

The solution, after transformation is

$\frac{n-1}{n}x^2+2\frac{1+...+(n-1)}{n^2}ax+\frac{1^2+...+(n-1)^2}{n^3}a^2$

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}((x+\frac{a}{n})^2+(x+\frac{2a}{n})^2+...+(x+\frac{(n-1)a}{n})^2)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x+\frac{k}{n}a)^2$$ and so we have that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x+\frac{k}{n}a)^2=\int_{0}^{1}(x+ta)^2 dt=x^2+\frac{a^2}{3}+ax+c$$

Comment: could you explain how did you transform the limit of the sum to the integral? something like Riemann sum?

Comment: @ِDear jermenkoo I'm sorry that late answer, this is just Riemann sum

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$1 + \cdots + (n - 1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2} - \frac{n}{2}$$

and

$$
1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + (n - 1)^2 = \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6} = \frac{n^3}{3} - \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is just the limit of the Riemann sum of $\displaystyle\int_{0}^1(x+a)^2da$, which is $\displaystyle x^2+x+\frac{1}{3}$.